# Calculate how many timespans are between two dates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

let's say I have a timespan variable that is a timespan that can be anything, from seconds, to hours, days... (I need to be able to set this in different ways).

I want to calculate how many timespans occurred between two given DateTime (like, say I have a timespan of 1 hour, how many hours passed between those two datetimes. But it can also be 1 hour and a half or 3 minutes...). I want this value returned as a floored integer (so, if 3.4 timespans have passed, it should return 3).

What's the best way to do it? I'm not familiar with datetime and I'm a little bit wrapping my head around this :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

`TimeSpan` comes down to the [`long Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property; you can simply perform integer division.

```
int x = 10 / 3; // equals 3

TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
TimeSpan difference = laterDateTime - earlierDateTime;

var periodFitsThisManyTimes = difference.Ticks / period.Ticks;
```